# Github API - create contents api method not triggering GitHub Pages build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, github-api, github-pages

I'm working on a Rails app that allows users to publish datasets via Github and access it via GitHub pages. I'm using the Github API to act as the user, create a repo and add the files, and everything works as expected, the only issue is that the GitHub pages page build doesn't seem to be happening. The datasets can be downloaded, but trying to access the index.html page doesn't seem to work at all.

Here's an example repo:

https://github.com/git-data-publisher/Foo

And here's the Github pages site:

http://git-data-publisher.github.io/Foo/

You can see that, for example:

http://git-data-publisher.github.io/Foo/data/June_2014.csv

Works fine.

I can only guess that this means the GitHub pages build isn't getting triggered. Any way I can make this happen without having to do a manual Git push?

You can also see my code here if this helps:

https://github.com/theodi/git-data-publisher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github tries to parse you site as a [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) site.

You must indicate that you're not using Jekyll by creating an empty **.nojekyll** file at the root of your repository.

Comment: Tried, and no dice unfortunately :( The [GitHub pages documentation](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages) suggests that it's only necessary if the site uses files or directories that start with underscores

Comment: I forked your repo here https://github.com/statiktest/Foo , added .nojekyll file and look http://statiktest.github.io/Foo/

Comment: Hmmmm. I wonder if that's because adding the `.nojekyll` file kicked off the Github pages build though. I tried adding one at first and it worked, but trying again from a fresh repo gave me the same result.

Comment: first repository generation can take up to 10 minutes

Comment: Ah, it's worked now. See http://git-data-publisher.github.io/Transactions-over-25-000-in-the-Foreign-and-Commonwealth-Office/

Thanks! :)

Comment: It's always a pleasure to help open data initiatives !